# .NET Core on linux when run got Permission denied

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

I have a new dotnet console project I created on Ubuntu 18.04, it is storage in a hdd shared with my windows and linux partition, at creation I got no errors, but when I tried to run it I got the following error message:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): Permission denied
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

But if I do the same in my Ubuntu partition the program runs with no problem.

Btw the project in the hhd have my user as owner and have all the permission to execute, write and read

Comment: Which file system type is your shared partition? FAT/NTFS? I think the linux permissions don't work on Windows file systems.

Comment: Could you show us the *path* which generates the exception?